# Pandas - describe table from DB - big data

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I want to use panda's describe method for a SQL table, but I can't pull all the data into memory - is it possible to use get the information using only sql queries?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is, as far as i know, not any way as convenient as df.describe() but there are sql-statements that could get you all the information that you want.

Below im using a stored procedure in SQL-server that returns all the columns and their datatypes. Looping through them to get all column names for float-type and then build new queries from them.

Then putting everything in a final dataframe. I only included 90 percentile but i think you can work out how to add more. You probably want to add more datatypes than float as well.

This solution is ugly and slow, but it worked for me where just pulling all the data to a dataframe failed on memory.

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd       

def sql2df(sql, connection):
    df = pd.read_sql(sql=sql, con=connection)
    return df

cnx = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=.\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=TEST;Trusted_Connection=yes;')

df_columns = sql2df('exec sp_columns test_table', cnx)[['COLUMN_NAME', 'TYPE_NAME']]

numeric_columns = []
for index, row in df_columns.iterrows():
    if row[1] == 'float': #or int or any numeric
        numeric_columns.append(row[0])

final_df = pd.DataFrame(index=(['stdev', 'count', '90%', 'mean']))

for col in numeric_columns:
    standard_dev = sql2df('SELECT STDEV('+col+') FROM dbo.test_table', cnx)\
        .get_value(0,0, takeable=True)

    cnt = sql2df('SELECT COUNT(' + col + ') FROM dbo.test_table', cnx)\
        .get_value(0,0, takeable=True)

    # percentile is 100-N so top 10 means 90 percentile
    ninety_percentile = sql2df('SELECT Min(subq.' + col + ') FROM(SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT ' + col +
                               ' FROM dbo.test_table ORDER BY ' + col + ' DESC) AS subq', cnx)\
        .get_value(0,0, takeable=True)

    mean = sql2df('SELECT AVG(' + col + ') FROM dbo.test_table', cnx)\
        .get_value(0,0, takeable=True)

    final_df[str(col)] = [standard_dev, cnt, ninety_percentile, mean]

print final_df
cnx.close()
```